# Stored Procedure with two options that execute different actions depending on their values

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2019, management

These were my instructions:

Create a stored procedure that receives two parameters:

`@i_action`

in which:

- 'I' = inserts a value
- 'U' = Updates values
- 'D' = Delete Values
- 'C' = Consult

and `@_option`

where

- 1 = cursor
- 2 = specific value

for `@i_action` it must go through the procedure.

On top of that:

- If `@i_action = 'C'` and `@i_option = 2` it must return a value indicating "Invalid option"
- if `@i_action = 'C'` and `@i_option = 1` it must go trough the table with an specific value

I am honestly at a lost as I have never done a stored procedure that is this complex (I have not even made an IF or CASE that is this complex)

this is what I am attempting right now:

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE TWOPTIONS
@i_action  varchar (1),
@i_option int,

AS

IF @i_option = 2

declare @value 

IF @i_action = 'I' Insert into Authors values ()
IF @i_action = 'U' Update Authors Set country = 
IF @i_action = 'C' Select * from Authors 
IF @i_action = 'D' delete from Authors where Name =
```

I am mostly struggling with the structure I am sure I can make the instructions work once I figure it out.

Comment: Hey @Bijujose , that is exactly where I am stuck, I feel as if I have to create 7 if options? Im not sure how to make it so if its one value it creates a pointer of it is another I just insert an individual value and how to create all those values within unless I go `IF @action = U and @option = 1, then @action = U and @option = 2` and so on? I feel as if I have to use nested if statements but I don't know how to use them in SQL

Answer (score 4):

In T-SQL, nested if statements can be achieved using the following pattern:

```
IF (<condition(s)>)
  BEGIN
    <Statement(s)>
  END
ELSE IF (<condition(s)>)
  BEGIN
    <Statement(s)>
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    <Statements(s)>
  END
```

Official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/else-if-else-transact-sql

Note: If you are executing a single statement the `BEGIN/END` is unnecessary.

So if you're trying to do:

> if @i_action = 'C' and @i_option = 2 it must return a value indicating "Invalid option" if @i_action = 'C' and @i_option = 1 it must go trough the table with an specific value

Then your code would look like:

```
IF (@i_action = 'C' AND @i_option = 2)
  RAISERROR('Invalid Option',16,1)
ELSE IF (@i_action = 'C')
  BEGIN
    <Do whatever>
  END
```

I'm not sure if your instructions were from homework, a job interview, or user requirements, but I'd *strongly* recommend splitting the stored procedure into four procedures as:

1. The arguments for each would vary (if I'm returning or deleting an 'Author' I only need the primary key to do so)
2. The permissions may vary
3. Each SP can be optimized independently, if needed

So `Author_Create`, `Author_Update`, `Author_Return`, `Author_Delete`.  No need to make things difficult by combining them.